# Cierre automático de etiqueta xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, label

estoy trabajando con C# para la construcción de un request para un Web Service, debo cerrar de la siguiente manera todas las etiquetas xml que no tengan algún valor al momento de cargar el documento xml con valores, por ejemplo:

```
<Nombre>Juan<Nombre>
<Apellido1>Lopez<Apellido1>
<Apellido2><Apellido2>
```

a

```
<Nombre>Juan<Nombre>
<Apellido1>Lopez<Apellido1>
<Apellido2/>
```

Para construir el documento xml utilizo XmlDocument.

Que sería viable para darle solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con XML `<Apellido2><Apellido2>` y `<Apellido2/>` y `<Apellido2 />` describen y definen exactamente lo mismo, un elemento de nombre `Apellido2` que no tiene ningún nodo hijo, ningún contenido, es decir, un elemento vacío. Como aparece un elemento vacío no cambia su significado, por eso me sorprende que haya un servicio que requiera o permita solo una de las variantes.

En cualquier lugar, en .NET, con System.Xml, la clase `XmlElement` define https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty?view=net-6.0 `IsEmpty`, es decir, si utilizas

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var apellido2 = doc.CreateElement("Apellido2");
apellido2.IsEmpty = true;
```

y entonces guardas el documento (en lo que que has insertado el elemento) con `doc.Save("result.xml")` debería tener la forma `<Apellido2/>` o `<Apellido2 />`.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado crear un objeto que gestione la etiqueta y el valor?

```
class EtiquetaXML
{
    public String Etiqueta { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public String Valor { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public String XML
    {
        get {
            if (Valor == String.Empty)
                return $"<{Etiqueta}/>";
            else
                return $"<{Etiqueta}>{Valor}</{Etiqueta}>";
        }
    }
}
```

Si lo usas así:

```
var nombre = new EtiquetaXML{Etiqueta = "Nombre", Valor = "Juan"};
var apellido1 = new EtiquetaXML{Etiqueta = "Apellido1", Valor = "Lopez"};
var apellido2 = new EtiquetaXML{Etiqueta = "Apellido2"};

Console.WriteLine($"{nombre.XML}\n{apellido1.XML}\n{apellido2.XML}");
```

Muestra [el siguiente resultado](https://tio.run/##lZBRS8MwFIWfk19xCXvYQDfca7eByF5kE2Gggu4h664lkCY1SSez5LfXNF3HdIj6kBDOud/h5Kb2MtUG67q0QmWw2luHeUJTya2Fe6Mzw3NaUdIKcyfeSnT8abmgJKikKDdSpLBypqE7GyrI0CVgm8vD9OAP53nh9skZ9sClNv9kYoNYgQQM4oOIV@i3YdOv/CDaxKArjYIem1RdVT@asSS6KC3@PDarYrCfjE60lvQ0Hk8psY670HGnxRaWXKi@jSWe18BNZgftznbcgNL5xmD4pcL3060ew4PF7uIQuzgsKCi3JVfMJ4cQXqCUYquvfsm57uZOoxa6wI/zrPEfs8YNGtgbrayWOHw0wuFCKOz3WNX@bhhY/6KqY83vwjgKbJA0y/N1/Qk):

> ```
> <Nombre>Juan</Nombre>
> <Apellido1>Lopez</Apellido1>
> <Apellido2/>
> ```

Comment: Como hay amplios APIs con .NET para crear XML bajo las reglas de la especificación de W3C no creo que sea una buena idea sugerir una implementación como la tuya porque con `var empresa = new EtiquetaXML{Etiqueta = "Empresa", Valor = "Johnson & Johnson" }` consigues una representación `<Empresa>Johnson & Johnson</Empresa>` rompiendo las reglas de XML mientras con System.Xml.Linq y `new XElement("Empresa", "Johnson & Johnson")` la representación es `<Empresa>Johnson &amp; Johnson</Empresa>`, como requiere la especificación.